# PHPDoc: document parent class method that always yields itself or descendant class?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Consider this code:

```
class ParentClass {

    public static function generate($className = __CLASS__){
        if(!$className) return new self();
        else return new $className();
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    /**
     * @param string $className
     * @return ChildClass
     */
    public static function generate($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::generate($className);
    }
}

var_dump($ChildClass::generate()); // object(ChildClass)[1]
```

`ChildClass::generate()` returns an instance of `ChildClass` wherever I use it because I never provide a `$className` argument. Problem is that my IDE gives me a warning about the `parent::generate()` call not matching the documented return type:

[image]

I would like to make this warning go away by adding documentation to the parent method. I could do:

```
@return ParentClass | ChildClass
```

Adding this to the parent method works but that's not practical because there are many dozen children classes, and there could be many more in the future. I have tried both of the following:

```
@return static
@return $className
```

but that hasn't made the warning go away. Is there a PHPDoc approved way to indicate that the calling child class will always be returned? Or -- more accurately -- that a class of type `$className` will be returned? If not, is there a way that works even with just my IDE? (`PhpStorm 2017.2`)

#### Update

@gogaz comment below got me to think: it would be enough if a PHPDoc `@return` could indicate something like `self | descendants`

Comment: PHP allows the `mixed` type, you could then use `@return mixed`

Comment: @gogaz thanks for the suggestion. Unless there is a more targeted way do document this, I think I'll take your suggestion. Maybe do `@return ParentClass|mixed`

Comment: `@return static` should do the job -- the `generate()` method is static and (at very least) PhpStorm should use the return type of the calling class.

Comment: @LazyOne that's what I thought also, but it doesn't work - try it :-)  `@return static` would work if code were calling `generate()` on the `ChildClass` itself I think. As it is, we're still calling it on the parent.

Comment: A bit off topic: since you can pass **any** class name ... the generated class may be ANY class (even `\DateTime` or whatnot) -- you do not have any checks (at very least in provided code) that would restrict class names to adhere some hierarchy.

Comment: @LazyOne It's not off-topic, and I realized that this complicates what I'm trying to do.  That's why I made the point to note in the OP why in my use case, `ChildClass` is always returned. Was just hoping there is a way to let the IDE know that from the parent class documentation. Or at least that a descendant of `ParentClass` could be returned. Maybe not.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Just suppress the warning .. as IDE is obviously wrong here.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Any more realistic code then? The provided code can be simplified to something like this: `public static function generate($className = null){ if (!$className) { $className = static::class; } return new $className(); }` so one method in parent class will not require override.

Comment: @LazyOne Wouldn't I have to suppress in every child class (there are lots)? I'm coming around to thinking that what I'm trying to do doesn't make sense because technically nothing is preventing a future child class from calling the parent with an unexpected class name. So maybe I shouldn't assume that a descendant is always returned. I'm now leaning towards `@return ParentClass|mixed` as the "proper" approach

Comment: @LazyOne that bit of code is really clever!! I actually can't change any code -- that's someone else's domain -- just the documentation... don't ask!

Comment: @BeetleJuice `mixed` means `anything`. If you are happy to typehint the variable that will hold instantiated class (`$zz = ChildClass::generate()`) then mixed is nice way to get rid of the warning (and pretty correct considering the situation). Alternative -- maybe try Advanced MetaData functionality (but that may not be super convenient for your code as it may require some definition repetition -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata)

Comment: @LazyOne actually because `ChildClass::generate()` itself is documented as returning `ChildClass`, PhpStorm knows it as such, regardless of the `mixed` return of the parent method.

Comment: @BeetleJuice *"Wouldn't I have to suppress in every child class (there are lots)?"* With original code -- yes -- I see no other choice as to have `generate()` overridden in each class (unless you will always pass the correct class name as a parameter).

Answer (score 2):

You can document parent class method and then just inherit that on a child class method.

```
class ParentClass
{
    /**
     * @param string $className
     * @return ChildClass
     */
    public static function generate($className = __CLASS__){
        if(!$className) return new self();
        else return new $className();
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function generate($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::generate($className);
    }
}
```

I hope that this will solve your problem.

***UPDATE***:
Another way to do this is by using interface that all classes will implement, so you could expect that your generate method will return some class that implements that interface.

```
 /**
  * ...
  * @return MyCustomInterface
  */
```

If this doesn't solve your issue... Then, you can set return type as "mixed", this will suppress warning and it won't lie :) because your generate method can return any class you specify via argument...

```
 /**
  * ...
  * @return mixed
  */
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Problem is that there isn't just one type `ChildClass`. I mentioned in the OP that there are dozens, and there could be many more in the future. So I need to write the parent's documentation assuming that the parent doesn't know the name of the calling child class

Comment: No. Because now `generate()` cannot return `ParentClass` (from documentation POV). Plus, as I understand, the `ParentClass` may not available be for making changes (3rd party code?)

Comment: @LazyOne I can change the documentation, just not the executable code.

Comment: @BeetleJuice But can you edit the code for `ChildClass`? If you can -- just write a better code for `generate()` and do not call parent one at all. In any case -- I strongly believe it's an IDE issue so should be handled/reported at JetBrains side.

Comment: @LazyOne no unfortunately I can't edit the child class file at all. At the risk of getting sidetracked, why do you think there's an IDE issue here? I figure if phpDoc doesn't provide a way to specify `this class or its descendants`, the IDE can't be blamed for correctly analyzing the existing docs

Comment: @BeetleJuice After thinking on it again -- not so sure now. In any case: 1) If I put `@return static` for `generate()` in parent class .. and NO PHPDoc for child -- IDE shows no complains ... but instantiated variable resolves to parent class only (If I add `one()` method into parent and `two()` into child, I see only `one()` in completion). 2) At the same time -- I could use `@return $this` (which is not really correct as `generate()` is a static method) and do that for both `generate()` methods ... I will have good code completion but complaining IDE on mismatched expected return...

Answer (score 0):

I've run across something similar (PHPStorm is more anal than PHP is on the subject). Unless there's some reason you HAVE to have it be specific to the child class, I would do this

```
class ParentClass {
    /**
     * @param string $className
     * @return ParentClass
     */
    public static function generate($className = __CLASS__){
        if(!$className) return new self();
        else return new $className();
    }
}
```

Remember, your `ChildClass` is still an instance of `ParentClass`

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't address the warning. Even without documentation, PhpStorm already determined that the parent's generator yielded `ParentClass` as you can tell from the text of the warning.

Comment: By the way, you're right of course `ChildClass` is a `ParentClass`, but the problem occurs because the IDE thinks I'm going the other way: trying to pass a `ParentClass` as a `ChildClass`.

Comment: Bleh. Was hoping it was close enough the same workaround would work here